# Can't find solution Failed to create directory 'activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB'

Tags: tomcat, activemq-classic

I am trying to integrate ActiveMQ with Tomcat on this tutorial 
[How to embed ActiveMQ in Tomcat](http://blog.octera.info/2011/06/how-to-embed-activemq-in-tomcat/)

When I start the server I am receiving Failed to create directory 'activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB'.

How can it be solved?

Also I don't know where to put parameters

```
-Dwebconsole.type=properties
```

-Dwebconsole.jms.url=tcp://localhost:61616
-Dwebconsole.jmx.url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/Jmxrmi

Log:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory 'activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB'
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore.size(KahaDBStore.java:1208)
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBPersistenceAdapter.size(KahaDBPersistenceAdapter.java:217)
    at org.apache.activemq.usage.StoreUsage.retrieveUsage(StoreUsage.java:56)
    at org.apache.activemq.usage.Usage.caclPercentUsage(Usage.java:283)
    at org.apache.activemq.usage.Usage.onLimitChange(Usage.java:188)
    at org.apache.activemq.usage.Usage.setLimit(Usage.java:172)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.getSystemUsage(BrokerService.java:1156)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.checkMemorySystemUsageLimits(BrokerService.java:2136)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:599)
    at info.octera.utils.LoadActiveMQ.init(LoadActiveMQ.java:32)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4921)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5231)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory 'activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB'
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOHelper.mkdirs(IOHelper.java:331)
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase.createPageFile(MessageDatabase.java:3118)
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase.getPageFile(MessageDatabase.java:3283)
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore.size(KahaDBStore.java:1206)
    ... 43 more

Comment: you need to put these parameters in the tomcat startup script $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh or catalina.bat  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12407817/6506229

Comment: can you post error logs

Comment: Today I moved eclipse and Tomcat into disk D and project is working. But how can I provide rights Tomcat to read and right on disk C in the folder C:\Program Files \eclipse\activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

on windows, I needed to specify the directory with a driver letter infront to get this working, ex

```
<amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="true" schedulerSupport="true" dataDirectory="c:\active-mq"> ....
```