# Why the RMI code is throwing AccessControlException?

Tags: java, rmi, policy, securitymanager

I have a java Class in which RMI code is written as :

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.setProperty("java.security.policy","file:/C:/myFloder/server.policy");
   
    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        log.info("Security manager installed.");
    } else {
        log.info("Security manager already exists.");
    }

    try {
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        log.info("java RMI registry created.");
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        log.info("java RMI registry already exists.");
    }
    Naming.unbind("//" + serverIp + ":1099/ServletPath");
    log.info("RMI stareted successfully...!!");
  }
}
```

Here is the server.policy :

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

But when I am trying to execute it , it is giving me same exceptions all the time . I have tried various solutions from the stackoverflow also but in vain.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:584)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
    at com.ist.ivision.rmi.server.SendOnQueueImpl.initMethod(SendOnQueueImpl.java:99)
    at com.ist.ivision.rmi.server.SendOnQueueImpl.main(SendOnQueueImpl.java:143)
    at com.ist.ivision.servlet.IVisionStartup$2.run(IVisionStartup.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "filepath/A.java" "write")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(SecurityManager.java:979)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:200)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)
```

Could anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong here ??

Thanks

Comment: When you run your code, do you get 

"Security manager installed." OR "Security manager already exists." ?

The reason I asks is because it might not be reading the policy file you specified..

Comment: @SusanMustafa I am getting "Security manager installed."

Comment: I think it is not finding your policy file....even if Java is not complaining.

Comment: @SusanMustafa How do I make it read the policy file ?

Comment: Why are you using a SecurityManager? You only need it for RMI if you're using the codebase feature. And why are you unbinding something from a newly created registry, which is therefore empty?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the existing java.policy file, the format looks different also.

// Standard extensions get all permissions by default

```
grant codeBase "file:${{java.ext.dirs}}/*" {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I would also double check that the path is correct to your custom .policy file.

A helpful Stackoverflow is: [Java RMI AccessControlException: access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427473/java-rmi-accesscontrolexception-access-denied)

===== Edited

Otherwise, try to remove the System.setProperty() from the code, and POINT to the custom policy file as a runtime argument from your IDE when you run:

> Remove System.setProperty()

Modify your Eclipse/Intellij and add the runtime arguments

> -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=C:/myFloder/server.policy

============= Edited 2

Try to do this instead of using a file:

```
    Policy.setPolicy(new Policy() {
        @Override
        public boolean implies(ProtectionDomain domain, Permission permission) {
            return true; // all permissions
        }
    });

    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
```

Comment: I tried this way also . I replaced "${{java.ext.dirs}}" with the absoute file path but still it is giving me the same exception @Susan Musafa

Comment: I did replace  "${{java.ext.dirs}}" with "file://C:/serverpath/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/*" but it is not helping out. I am placing the jar files to the tomcat context . There how do I do this : "-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=C:/myFloder/server.policy"

Comment: I didnt meant modify your policy file.   I was wondering if you could modify your System.setProperty() to point to file:// instead of file:/  but do TRY to point to the policy file as a runtime argument RATHER than in the code, see if that could help.   TO at least eliminate the possible path issues

Comment: But I am not executing the code from eclipse IDE . I am creating the jar and then deploying it to the tomcat container. There how do I provide runtime arguments ?

Comment: For Tomcat, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407163/pass-vm-argument-to-apache-tomcat  It shows you how to pass arguments.

Comment: Nopes, it is not working that way also . Giving out the same error

Comment: I tried the edited code , now that exception has gone but "java.lang.SecurityException: attempt to add a Permission to a readonly Permissions object" this exception occured

Comment: I got the solution , I need to refresh the policies by ```Policy.getPolicy().refresh()``` only rest of things were right posted in my question.