# How to read Ubuntu environment variables into SpringBoot Program?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu

Here's what I do in SpringBoot on Windows to read an environment variable (location of log folder).

1. In Windows Server, I set a System environment variable for "LOG_HOME" with the value with the directory that SpringBoot should use to write logs.
2. In SpringBoot's application.properties, I have:

logging.file.name= ${LOG_HOME}/ws.log

Works great!

---

But in Ubuntu Linux 20.04, the same approach doesn't work for me at all.

When the WAR file tries to deploy on Ubuntu 20.04 using this similar technique:

1. (in .bashrc): export LOG_HOME = /home/ubuntu/logs
2. reboot (to reload the environment for sure)

I get this error in the Tomcat log when trying to deploy the WAR file:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'LOG_HOME' in value "${LOG_HOME}/ws.log"

So, it seems that Spring doesn't see the environment variable set in Ubuntu.

I wrote a simple Java program just to check the value of the environment variables and they were all created as expected including the LOG_HOME as shown in Linux "printenv".

If possible, I need a technique that will work on Ubuntu without changing the working SpringBoot implementation on Windows Server.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: instead of exporting in shell session export LOG_HOME = /home/ubuntu/logs try this as -D argument in your starup command 
eg: java -cp=xxx main -DLOG_HOME=/home/ubuntu/log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of exporting in shell session like

```
export LOG_HOME = /home/ubuntu/logs
```

try this as -D VM argument in your starup command
eg:
`java -cp=xxx mainclass -DLOG_HOME=/home/ubuntu/log`

if you are using tomcat then :
VM args can be added  `catalina.sh file under CATALINA_OPTS.`

Comment: For a SpringBoot application, where would that command be? It's a WAR file. Also, would I access it the same way in application.properties? Thx.

Comment: same would work for SB app also where are you deploying your war ?
if you paste your startup script i can help

Comment: Where is the "java...." done? This is a WAR file in Tomcat. Sorry I'm missing this, but this information will be very helpful once I understand how to use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407163/pass-vm-argument-to-apache-tomcat
please refer to this

Comment: Also that explains why your export is not working , tomcat is staring in a separate shell session than your export command that is  the reason it is not able to resolve the env var
if you want to do it for tomcat , you need tocd /opt/tomcat/bin/ 
sudo nano setenv.sh  something like this to add to your tomcat statup

Comment: This is a bit confusing to me since there is a Tomcat9 "bin" folder in two places so far I've found. I think the one I want to change (the setenv.sh) is in /usr/share/tomcat9/bin. Does that sound right?

Comment: you can try that alternative is read the tomcat 9 doc 
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/RUNNING.txt
On *nix, $CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251275/discussion-between-morkus-and-satyesht).

Answer (score 1):

For tomcat, add your environment variables to `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/setenv.sh` where `$TOMCAT_HOME` is the directory of your tomcat installation.

Comment: This works great on Windows, but not at all on Ubuntu 20. Thanks.

Comment: On Ubuntu, you added them to setenv.sh and not setenv.bat, correct?  setenv.sh is absolutely where you need to specify environment variables to be used by tomcat, that's its purpose, to configure the environment.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. setenv.sh, but SpringBoot would not see the variable even though it was shown in the ubuntu printenv listing. The solution that worked for me was given above by the extremely helpful and kind "satyesht". That solution was to create a line in the catalina.sh file under CATALINA_OPTS.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me posted by the extremely helpful satyesht above, was to edit the Catalina.sh file and add the "-D" name-value pair option under CATALINA_OPTS. Thanks to all who posted. :)